# Как запретить увеличение экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

На любом сенсорном устройстве есть возможность увеличить экран пальцами. Подскажите, как можно это отключить?

Comment: @PavelNazarian разве этот референс не относится ко всем Touch событиям сразу? В данном вопроса автор упоминает только об увеличении экрана пальцами, и некорректно будет отсылать сразу целый блок событий, к тому же в этой статье я не нашёл возможного решения на вопроса автора.

Comment: @PavelNazarian в прицепе ваш вариант можно применить как ответ, но только как костыль, так как к примеру есть я буду выделять текст двумя пальцами то сайт не даст мне это сделать(Я часто это могу делать, к примеру в статьях и т.п.), а в Stackoverflow ответы должны либо быть точно по вопросу либо быть довольно универсальными.(По моему мнению конечно)

Answer (score 0):

Видимо на другом ресурсе автор тоже задавал подобный вопрос.
Продублирую ответ сюда, чтобы было. (ответ не мой)

Можно добавить метатег:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0">
```